# Working on Significance testing of a hypothesis

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I have a question as follows:

> Assuming the null hypothesis is true for all cases. If we perform multiple pairwise comparisons at the $\alpha = 0.05$ level, what is the probability of making type I error with AT LEAST ONE of the tests?

The correct answer is greater than 0.05, and I don't know why.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with statistical significance--could I ask for some clarification? Is α the probability that some event occurs in one trial, and are you searching for the probability that that event occurs at least once in n trials?

Answer (score 1):

I may have misinterpreted the above question--please let me know if so! I do not have much of a statistical background.

The probability of not making said error in each trial is $1-.05=.95$. So over $n$ trials, you have a probability of $.95^n$ of the error never occurring, and the probability of it occurring at least once (this is the complement of the situation where the error never occurs) is $1-.95^n$.

But since .95 is less than 1, when $n>1$, we have $.95^n<.95$, so $1-.95^n>1-.95=.05$   .